# If N,E & T are distict positive integers such that ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

[image]

What I see that $2013=3 \times 11 \times 61$ . So, one possible sum of N,E & T is $ \,\,3 +11 +61=75$ . I am not sure what to do next as none of the options has $75$ as a possible choice but as $75$ divides $675$ so I think option 3 may be a possible choice. But , still it is not clear to me. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let N=1, E=3, then what must be the value of T?

Comment: Thanks @John. Got your point.